# remove close icon from the google map info window

Tags: javascript, google-maps

How to remove close icon of info window in google map. I tried to remove this icon, but couldn't find id or class for that.

So can anyone help me to remove close icon from info window?

Answer (score 35):

You can hide close button with CSS:

```css
.gm-style-iw + div {display: none;}
```

Answer (score 18):

This worked for me with just css

```
.gm-ui-hover-effect {
    display: none !important;
}
```

Comment: I'm using `@angular/google-maps` and I had to do it like this `::ng-deep .gm-ui-hover-effect`

Answer (score 2):

I tried all suggestions above, but failed. I tried using jquery `$('.gm-style-iw').next().hide()`, it did not work as well.

This is what worked for me, in case someone needs it. This is what I did with GMAP API V3.

```
.gm-style .gm-style-iw + div {
    display: none; /* <-- this will generally work on the fly. */
    visibility: hidden; /* this 2 lines below are just for hard hiding. :) */
    opacity: 0;
}
```

Generally, what it does is, it looks for direct sibling of that `gm-style-iw` which is created dynamically by the API. The `div` right next to the `gm-style-iw` is the close button.

Hope that helps. :)

Answer (score 2):

```
button.gm-ui-hover-effect {
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

That works as at today in Chrome and Edge

Answer (score 1):

You can try this

```
::ng-deep .gm-style .gm-style-iw-c button {
    display: none !important;
}
```

The magic inside it is ::ng-deep modifier that can search deeply for the styles and override them.

Answer (score 0):

For people using Google Maps API v2, this function will open an info window with no close icon:

```
openInfoWindowHtml(html, {
  maxWidth: 200, buttons: { close: { visible: false } }
});
```

Comment: where do i insert in my code. my sample code `marker.setMap(map);
   $('body').append('<div id="targetdiv" style="height: 50px; width: 50px;"></div>')
 $("#targetdiv").load('ProgressBar1.jsp');
 var innerhtml=document.getElementById("targetdiv");
 var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
      content: innerhtml,
      maxWidth:200, 
      buttons:{close:{visible: false}},
      

   });
 
 infowindow.open(map,marker); 
 //openInfoWindowHtml(document.getElementById("targetdiv"), {maxWidth:200, buttons:{close:{visible: false}}});
 marker.setMap(map);`

Comment: You are already have the code: `buttons:{close:{visible:false}}`. It should work, what browser are you using?

Comment: i am using mozilla firefox 24.0

Comment: This answer is dated. It applies to Google Maps API 2, which Google no longer supports. The new API doesn't have an openInfoWindowHtml function.

Answer (score 0):

I did it setting `closeBoxURL` to an empty string on the options object

```
infoboxOptions = {

    closeBoxURL: '',
    ...

}

var infobox = new InfoBox(infoboxOptions);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
.gm-style-iw + div{ display: none; } // hide div

.gm-style-iw + div + img{ display: none; } // hide img
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.gm-style-iw button>img {
    display: none!important;
}
```

This code piece will make it to work. In my case image representing the close button was inside button tag in div classed gm-style-iw

Answer (score 0):

Add this in your CSS:

```
button.gm-ui-hover-effect {
   visibility: hidden;
}
```

This worked perfectly with Maps API v3.43