# How do I remove 'close' button from InfoWindow in react-google-maps?

Tags: react-google-maps

Havent been able to figure out how to do this, is there a way to target with css or is it an option in the lib?

Answer (score 4):

Per [official documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/infowindows):

> The `InfoWindow` class does not offer customization.

Even though it is possible *to override Google Maps API CSS* to hide close button as demonstrated, for example, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26454758/1375553), the recommended way would be to *create a fully customized popup*, in case of `react-google-maps` library, [`OverlayView` component](https://github.com/tomchentw/react-google-maps/blob/master/src/components/OverlayView.md) is a good candidate for that matter:

```
import React from "react";
import { OverlayView } from "react-google-maps";

const getPixelPositionOffset = pixelOffset => (width, height) => ({
  x: -(width / 2) + pixelOffset.x,
  y: -(height / 2) + pixelOffset.y
});

const Popup = props => {
  return (
    <OverlayView
      position={props.anchorPosition}
      mapPaneName={OverlayView.OVERLAY_MOUSE_TARGET}
      getPixelPositionOffset={getPixelPositionOffset(props.markerPixelOffset)}
    >
      <div className="popup-tip-anchor">
        <div className="popup-bubble-anchor">
          <div className="popup-bubble-content"><h1>{props.content}</h1></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </OverlayView>
  );
};
```

[**Demo**](https://codesandbox.io/s/5vzy4p30wx)